# jQuery if statement to check if a value exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, searchbar

I am creating an input that searchs through a list and checks if the value entered exists within the list, this works fine apart from when I enter a value then delete it so that no value exists within the input all the list items are displayed block. If no value exists within the input I want to hide all the list items. Here's what I have so far;

```js
$('#prod_search').keyup( function(){
 search();
});

function search(){
    var input, filter, ul, li, sku, i, title;
    input = jQuery("#prod_search");
    filter = input.val().toUpperCase();
    ul = jQuery("#prod_list");
    li = ul.find("li");

    for(i = 0; i < li.length; i++){
        sku = li[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
        title = li[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[1];
        
        if(sku.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 || title.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1){
            li[i].style.display = "block";
        }else{
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#prod_list li{
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 


<input type="text"  placeholder="Product Search" id="prod_search">

<ul id="prod_list">
    <li>
        <p>2342dhsa-1</p>
        <p>test 2 (Copy)</p>
    </li>

    <li>
        <p>01234dfwe</p>
        <p>test 5</p>
    </li>

    <li>
        <p>2343sdfg</p>
        <p>test 4</p>
    </li>

    <li>
        <p>2342sdff</p>
        <p>test 3</p>
    </li>

    <li>
        <p>2342dhsa</p>
        <p>test 2</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the input value, if empty then hide all and `return false` else nothing to do with your code, Use

```
if(filter == '') {
 $('#prod_list li').hide();
 return false;
}
```

in your search function

```js
$('#prod_search').keyup( function(){
 search();
});

function search() {    
    var input, filter, ul, li, sku, i, title;
    input = jQuery("#prod_search");
    filter = input.val().toUpperCase();
    if(filter == '') {
     $('#prod_list li').hide();
     return false;
    }
    ul = jQuery("#prod_list");
    li = ul.find("li");

    for(i = 0; i < li.length; i++){
        sku = li[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
        title = li[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[1];
        
        if(sku.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 || title.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1){
            li[i].style.display = "block";
        }else{
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#prod_list li{
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 


<input type="text"  placeholder="Product Search" id="prod_search">

<ul id="prod_list">
    <li>
        <p>2342dhsa-1</p>
        <p>test 2 (Copy)</p>
    </li>

    <li>
        <p>01234dfwe</p>
        <p>test 5</p>
    </li>

    <li>
        <p>2343sdfg</p>
        <p>test 4</p>
    </li>

    <li>
        <p>2342sdff</p>
        <p>test 3</p>
    </li>

    <li>
        <p>2342dhsa</p>
        <p>test 2</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

check for the input value before performing the search.

```
function search() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, sku, i, title;
  input = jQuery("#prod_search");
  filter = input.val().toUpperCase();
  ul = jQuery("#prod_list");
  li = ul.find("li");
  if (input != '') {
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
      sku = li[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
      title = li[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[1];

      if (sku.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 || title.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        li[i].style.display = "block";
      } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  } else {
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a much simpler way to do this.

Just check for the `length` of your value then if it is more than 0 `hide()` everything and only `show()` the `<li>`s you have filtered with `.filter()` :

```js
$('#prod_search').keyup( function(){
  if(this.value.length){
    $('#prod_list li').hide().filter((_,e) => e.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText.includes(this.value) || e.getElementsByTagName('p')[1].innerText.includes(this.value)).show();
  }else{
    $('#prod_list li').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
#prod_list li{
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 


<input type="text"  placeholder="Product Search" id="prod_search">

<ul id="prod_list">
    <li>
        <p>2342dhsa-1</p>
        <p>test 2 (Copy)</p>
    </li>

    <li>
        <p>01234dfwe</p>
        <p>test 5</p>
    </li>

    <li>
        <p>2343sdfg</p>
        <p>test 4</p>
    </li>

    <li>
        <p>2342sdff</p>
        <p>test 3</p>
    </li>

    <li>
        <p>2342dhsa</p>
        <p>test 2</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you want is to hide all the items when the input has no value or has a value that do not exists in any of the items in the list.

function search(){
    var input, filter...
    ...

```
for(i = 0; i < li.length; i++){

    // no filter, don't display the items.
    if (!filter)
    {
       li[i].style.display = "none";
       continue;
    }

    var sku = li[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
    var title = li[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[1];
    ...
    if(sku.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1...) { ... }
```

}